# AWS Cognito JWT token validation

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am trying to enforce security based on AWS Cognito JWT token, the source is at https://github.com/IxorTalk/ixortalk.aws.cognito.jwt.security.filter.

But I have concern, which is per documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-using-id-and-access-tokens-in-web-api

It says "The ID token expires one hour after the user authenticates. You should not process the ID token in your client or web API after it has expired."

Which is the error I am seeing in my logs,
com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.BadJWTException: Expired JWT. I assume, that the JWT token has already expired, what would be my steps to successfully enforce token based authorization?

Comment: You uses the refresh token to get new id+refresh+access tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, The way I have programmed is this,

```
    // Parse the Cognito Keys and get the key by kid
    // Key is just a class that is used for parsing JSON to POJO
    Key key = this.keyService.getKeyByKeyId(JWT.decode(token).getKeyId());

    // Use Key's N and E
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(key.getN()));
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(key.getE()));

    // Create a publick key
    PublicKey publicKey = null;
    try {
        publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // Throw error
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // Throw error
    }

    // get an algorithm instance
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) publicKey, null);

    // I verify ISS field of the token to make sure it's from the Cognito source
    String iss = String.format("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s", REGION, POOL_ID);

    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
            .withIssuer(iss)
            .withClaim("token_use", "id") // make sure you're verifying id token
            .build();

    // Verify the token
    DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

    // Parse various fields
    String username = jwt.getClaim("sub").asString();
    String email = jwt.getClaim("email").asString();
    String phone = jwt.getClaim("phone_number").asString();
    String[] groups = jwt.getClaim("cognito:groups").asArray(String.class);
```

I am using this repo to verify and parsing of the tokens,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure you are importing the following,

```
    import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
    import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
    import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
    import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException;
    import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

If the token is expired, it won't be varified.

Answer (score 0):

You need the refresh token, that helps you get new identity and access tokens. The Cognito JS SDK refreshes the token automatically.

Now in your case, seems like you need to call the RefreshToken and add a check to see if the token is expired.

The identity/access tokens come with a expiration time so this is something you can do locally in your application before you use them.

Comment: Hi, cognito return refresh token with other data. Do I need to constantly check if id token is expired and request it if it has expired?